# Javascript, how to await multiple promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

What I want to accomplish:

- gather artist id`s

  - either finding them in the db
  - or creating them
- creating an event in the db, getting the event_id
- waiting till both are done, artists and event id`s gathered
- now looping over the artist, event combinations

What I got:

I`m working with Node and mysql. To insert the relations I have to wait for the artists to insert or create. I try to accomplish with the following code:

```
let promises = [];

if (artists.length != 0) {
    for (key in artists) {
        promises.push( find_artist_id_or_create_new_artist(artists[key]) )
    }
}

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Returning an id:

```
async function find_artist_id_or_create_new_artist(artist_name) {
    return await find_artist_return_id(artist_name, create_artist_return_id)
}
```

Finding an artist:

```
async function find_artist_return_id(artist_name, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE `name` LIKE "+con.escape(artist_name)+" LIMIT 1;"

    con.query(sql, (err,row) => {
      if(err) throw err;

      if (row.length == 0) {
        return callback(artist_name)
      } else {
        return row[0].id
      }
    });
}
```

Creating an artist

```
async function create_artist_return_id(artist_name) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `name`, `meta_1`, `meta_2`) VALUES (NULL, "+con.escape(artist_name)+", NULL, NULL)";

    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) throw err;

      return result.insertId
    });
}
```

I understand that I cant return in a con.query function, but I dont how to properly setup the code to get this done. A link to, or help how to search for an answer is appreciated.

Comment: Mixing mySql callbacks and promises won't work.  An easy solution is to use a wrapper for mySql that's already got the callback converted into Promises.. eg..  https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend a source when async can and cant work?

Comment: Your fundamental `SQL functions` need to be converted to `promises` in order to be `awaited`.

Comment: `await` can wait on any Promise,  `async` is just a means of making a function return a `Promise`,  but if inside this function you use callbacks you have broken the Promise.  So in above if you just using the Promise version of mySQL you would do -> `var result = await con.query(sql)` instead, basically the callbacks are not used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your fundamental `SQL functions` need to be converted to `promises` in order to be `awaited`.

See [`Async Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info.

```
// Artist Ids.
const artistIds = await Promise.all(artists.map(async (artist) => await findArtist(artist) || await createArtist(artist)))

// Find Artist.
const findArtist = artist => new Promise((resolve, reject) => con.query(`SELECT * FROM \`artists\` WHERE \`name\` LIKE ${con.escape(artist)} LIMIT 1;`, async (error, row) => {
  if(error) return reject(error)
  if (!row.length) return resolve(await createArtist(artist)) 
  return resolve(row[0].id)
}))

// Create Artist.
const createArtist = artist => new Promise((resolve, reject) => con.query(`INSERT INTO \`artists\` (\`id\`, \`name\`, \`meta_1\`, \`meta_2\`) VALUES (NULL, ${con.escape(artist)}, NULL, NULL)`, (error, result) => {
  if (error) return reject(error)
  return resolve(result.insertId)
}))
```

Comment: Nice one :) just expand the explanation, then its the perfect answer ...

Comment: Worked, to get it working these are the things I had to edit:

add await:

const artistIds = await Promise.all(artists.map(async (artist) => await findArtist(artist) || await createArtist(artist)))

add argument:

const createArtist = (artist_name) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => con.query(`INSERT INTO \`artists\` (\`id\`, \`name\`, \`meta_1\`, \`meta_2\`) VALUES (NULL, ${con.escape(artist_name)}, NULL, NULL)`, (error, result) => {
  if (error) return reject(error)
  return resolve(result.insertId)
}))

can you edit this and that i then accept this as the answer?

Comment: My bad ahah. Thanks for pointing those out! Glad it worked  @bartgreat

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap the mysql callbacks into promises:

```
 function find_artist_return_id(artist_name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var sql = "SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE `name` LIKE "+con.escape(artist_name)+" LIMIT 1;"

      con.query(sql, (err,row) => {
         if(err) return reject(err);

         if (row.length == 0) {
           return resolve(artist_name);

           return resolve(row[0].id);      
      });
   });
}
```

And by the way, this is very ugly:

```
 if (artists.length != 0) {
   for (key in artists) {
```

Just do:

```
  for(const artist of artists)
    promises.push(someApiCall(artist));
```

or:

```
  const promises = artists.map(someApiCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way is to use already existing **ORM** like **sequalizejs** or etc they return promise for you and instead of running find and create in separate Raw query in native MySQL driver. You can  simply use API'S like find or create something.

i explain you how async works in your example , i took a piece of code from your example.

```
    async function createArtist(artist_name) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `name`, `meta_1`, `meta_2`) VALUES (NULL, "+con.escape(artist_name)+", NULL, NULL)";

    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        return result.insertId
    });
}

const artistId = (async () => {
    await createArtist('maxi');
})();
```

look into **createArtist** function this is exactly what you have . Three things you have to note here,

1. you declare it a async function so it  return promise in default.
2. it can simply return anything like normal function ,if it is a synchronous function avoid using async.
3. As you said you cannot return anything from callback . since it is asynchronous you have to return promise.

so the code can be changed to

```
    async function createArtist(artist_name) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `name`, `meta_1`, `meta_2`) VALUES (NULL, "+con.escape(artist_name)+", NULL, NULL)";

        con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(result.insertId)
        });
    });
}

const artistId = (async () => {
    await createArtist('maxi');
})();
```

Things changed here , added  native promise wrapper and return it, before it goes asynchronous. called resolve to make success . And reject to make it fail.

Don't forget to add try ...catch blog for await's to handle error.